# What does the .NET CLR do with the memory overhead in empty types?

Tags: .net, clr

All .NET classes have sync block and type pointers stored as part of their instances. These take up a total of 8 bytes in 32-bit processes and 16 bytes in 64-bit processes. However, the object size of an instance of an empty type is 12 and 24 bytes, respectively.

I've seen some articles saying it is an alignment issue, but since the sync block and type handle are pointer-sized, I don't understand why any padding needs to be added.

Other articles say that the garbage collector needs it, but what does it do with the overhead? It can't store anything there because that extra space is actually used if a type has instance fields. Does the garbage collector do something with that memory some time after object finalization and before it is freed that it needs a place to put something (maybe a pointer)?

Here are some of the articles I have read regarding empty type sizes:

[Performance Considerations of Class Design and General Coding in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/812678/Performance-Considerations-of-Class-Design-and-Gen):

> If you made an object with no fields and looked at it in the debugger, you would notice that its size is actually 12 bytes, not 8. For 64-bit processes, the object would be 24 bytes. This is because the minimum size is based on alignment. Thankfully, this "extra" 4 bytes of space will be used by a field.

[Of memory and strings](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/):

> There’s a "minimum" size of 12 bytes and 24 bytes respectively. In other words, you can’t have a type which is just the overhead. Note how the "Empty" class takes up the same size as creating instances of Object… there’s effectively some spare room, because the CLR doesn’t like operating on an object with no data.

[Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20150515023057/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx):

> As discussed previously, the current GC implementation needs an object instance of at least 12 bytes. If a class does not have any instance fields defined, it will carry an overhead of 4 bytes. The rest of the 8 bytes will be taken up by the Object Header (which may contain a syncblk number) and TypeHandle.

Comment: "the object size of an instance of an empty type is 12 and 24 bytes" - Did you read this somewhere?

Comment: Alignment is a *very* important processor implementation detail.  It provides the basic guarantees of the .NET memory model.  Atomicity is important, especially for object references.  You couldn't write threaded code without it.

Comment: @dcastro I edited my question to include references to some of the articles I have read regarding empty type sizes.

Comment: @HansPassant But the 8 and 16 bytes for the type/sync block pointers are already aligned. I'm not sure how having 12 and 24 byte sizes helps with alignment.

Comment: The point is that the *next* object in memory needs to be aligned as well.  That can only happen when an object is a multiple of 4 bytes in 32-bit mode, of 8 bytes in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Right. But 8 is already a multiple of 4. And 16 is already a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I see what is going on.

Arrays store their length as the first 4 or 8 bytes (in 32 and 64-bit systems, respectively) of their instance field data (after the type pointer). In order to get the size of memory usage, the CLR gets the base size from the method table (pointed to by the type pointer) and adds the length multiplied by the per-item size (which it also gets from the method table).

In other words, the formula is:

> memory size = base size + length * item size

Rather than have one formula for arrays and a different one for other types, the implementors of the CLR wanted to have a single formula for both, thus eliminating the need for any conditional logic when getting the memory size.

But how could that work? Other object types don't store a length in the first 4 or 8 bytes of their instance field data.

The key is the item size, which is stored in the method table. For non-array types, the item size is 0. This means that length * item size will always be 0 regardless of the value stored in the first 4 or 8 bytes of the instance field data, and the formula will work.

But even though the value of the first 4 or 8 bytes of instance field data doesn't matter, it still needs to be allocated to prevent access violations.

Thanks to Hans for pointing me to the SetFree method. Once I saw that the CLR was essentially converting an arbitrary object to a 1-dimensional byte array, I realized that it was assuming that everything could be converted in that manner, and the investigation into why led me to this answer.

Comment: I'm very curious as to why this answer was downvoted. It seems to me the OP made an outstanding job at researching this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, even an empty class requires 4/8 bytes for the section of the object that normally stores the fields of the object.  So a completely empty class still takes 4 + 4 + 4 = 12 bytes in 32-bit mode, 8 + 8 + 8 = 24 bytes in 64-bit mode.  Those 4/8 extra bytes are simply not used when the object exists.

This storage is required when the object is released.  It can then become part of the free block list of a heap segment.  This happens if the heap segment contains pinned objects and could not be compacted perfectly.  In that case, the sync block is set to -1 in the debug build, the type handle is set to the internal fake FreeObject type.  And the object size takes 4 bytes.

Visible from the [SSCLI20 source code](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=4917), clr/src/vm/gcsmp.cpp file, SetFree() function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the SetFree function! Looking at that method was very informative, and led me to realize why the extra memory was needed. It looks like the extra bytes aren't strictly only needed after the object is converted to the FreeObject type. But it can be converted to that type because the minimum size requirement means there will always be room for a length field, and the FreeObject type is basically a 1-dimensional byte array.